# How to expand div larger than parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a browser-based video game. In the game, objects have a graphic and a title bar. The title bar holds their name, the spell they are currently casting, cast completion %, and spell icon. Objects have a size (dimensions) as determined by the server.

I want to attach the title bar to the object. I want the title bar to show the icon, with the spell name inline with it. If spell icon width + spell name width > object width, i want to stretch the title bar horizontally (and preferably center it over the object)

The behavior I am currently seeing is that the spell name will stay inline UNTIL the spell name width + spell icon width > object width, at which point the name will appear on the next line, instead of stretching the title bar (and I can't try to center it if it's not larger).

The solution may include javascript, as the game loop will update the object, including the position, size, graphic, spell icon, spell name, and cast completion % using javascript.

"supercontainer" is the object. "container" is the title bar. So I want "container" to expand larger than "supercontainer" width when "first" and "second" are big enough. The size of "first" is fixed because all spell icons are the same size.

```
<div class="supercontainer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second">Words are long</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the css

```
.supercontainer {
   position: absolute;
   left: 10px; /* example */
   top: 10px; /* example */
   width: 64px;
   height: 64px;
   background-color: black;
 }

 .container {
   min-width:100px;
   background-color: red;
 }

 .first {
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   background-color: blue;
   display: inline-block;
 }

 .second {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is a link to a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ch901rL2/3/

Comment: put `white-space: nowrap;` on the `.second`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your `container` CSS rule like below will keep its children on 1 line.

```
.container {
  min-width:100px;
  background-color: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;    /* this make containter grow with children */
}
```

Comment: This causes the children to sit next to one another, but it does not make the parent larger. I have a border around the title bar that I want to center so the title bar has to expand.

Comment: @ZachTaylor Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try **changing** your `.container` element to this:

```
.container {
  min-width:100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block; //adding this will allow it to grow according to the text
}
```

Also, **add** `white-space: no-wrap;` to the needed elements such as `.second`.

Comment: This works as long as "white-space: nowrap;" is on .container, instead of .second